# Should child class override the constructors if they have identical parameter as the parent class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, visual-c++, constructor

I am using VC++.

I define a parent class:

```
class A
{
   A();
   A(int a);

   virtual ~A();

   virtual void DoSomething();
}
```

Then define a child class:

```
class B: public A
{
   virtual void DoSomething();
}
```

In class B, only a new version of DoSomething is introduced. All other functions, including the constructors and destructor are same as A.

For example, both the following constructor are OK for B:

```
B MyB;
B MyB(1);
```

In such a case, need I create the constructors B() and B(int a)?

I try to obmit the constructors & destructor in B(), hoping it can inherit from A, but the compiler will report error for:

```
B MyB(1);
```

Comment: On another couple of notes, the `virtual` keyword is only needed in the top-most base-class. And I really recommend that you use the special identifier `override` when overriding functions (as in `class B : public A { public: void DoSomething() override; };`)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Sorry for my mistake, I have fixed the error. B inherits from A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default constructor `B::B()` would be [implicitly-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor), while `B::B(int)` won't. You can define one explicitly, or apply `using` for [inheriting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) (since C++11).

> If the *using-declaration* refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. `using Base::Base;`), all constructors of that base (ignoring member access) are made visible to overload resolution when initializing the derived class.

```
class B : public A
{
   using A::A;
   virtual void DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but using Base::Base seems not working for Visual C++ 2008?

Comment: @alancc Sorry it's a C++11 feature. VC 2008 doesn't support it, definately. I think you have to define `B::B(int)` by yourself.